# Using two versions of one library in a project

Tags: c++, cmake, namespaces, dependencies, multiple-versions

There is a stable and rarely modified *c++ & cmake & gcc/msvs* project which statically uses, say, version 1.0 of our `libfoo` library for object recognition. Our customer now wants some new functionality (a detector of a new type of specific objects) which demands to use `libfoo` version 2.0.

Upgrading `libfoo` from version 1.0 to 2.0 in the whole project is not an option for a few reasons, the primary being that it will change recognition behaviour in an undesired way (so subsequent painstaking tweaking would be necessary to come back to the previous quality levels and we are not paid for this work).

I see the following bruteforce solution:

1. Wrap all version 2.0 source files with `namespace foo20 {...}`
2. Rename version 2.0 cmake target names from `foo` to `foo-2.0`.
3. From the main program link to `foo-2.0` to implement the new functionality.

Apart from 'niceness', this solution is cumbersome for in fact `libfoo` depends on a bunch of other our internal libraries and the procedure above should be repeated for each of them.

Does anyone know a better solution for the whole problem or at least for one of the steps?

Comment: Tell the customer it's paid work and then migrate to libfoo2.0 for the whole project ;)

Comment: @UKMonkey, tweaking recognition quality would be times more expensive than injecting `libfoo-2.0`, we definitely cannot go this way. I just wanna know a nicer way to inject.

Comment: My application has multiple versions of multiple libraries in one project.  I highly recommend avoiding this kind of situation.  Regardless of the lifetime guaranteed job security.

Comment: How about merge the required features from 2.0 into 1.0?  You really really don't want 2 versions of the same library like this.

Comment: Guys, I understand that in general case we should have simply migrated from 1.0 to 2.0, it's common good practice, but in recognition software there are specific problems which we try to avoid.

Comment: I would say it also depends on :
1/ is libfoo a static or  dynamically library ? 
2/ Do you have a branch for this particular client on your versionning system
3/ Do you expect/ do you have so,e sort or requirements of  API /ABI compatibility between libfoo2.0 and libfoo1.0 ?

Comment: 1. Static.
2. This is the only client for this particular system.
3. API is mostly compatible between 1.0 and 2.0.